# Polymer 2 define global variables

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I recently started working with Polymer 2.0, and so far i am in love with it.
I am used to Angular in combination with typescript, and i loved how easy it was to define global variables.

Wanted outcome:
Let's say i have a variable named: "Username" in the login page.
The var Username is currently "Guest", so in my welcome-page i have the message "Hello Guest!". The username in the login page changes from guest => not-a-guest
The welcome-page now says: Hello not-a-guest!".

Is there a way to do this without passing the variable like
? Because everytime I want to use the username property, i now have to pass the username like above. (so if i need the username in a child of a child of a child component, I now have to pass the username to all parents aswell). Now ofcourse this is about a user so in this case, localstorage/sessionstorage would be alright, but this is just an example. I'd like to use the global defining for something else, and saving that in localstorage would not be ideal.

I found a lot of Polymer 1 solutions, but i'd love to have my application in full Polymer 2.0.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured and make a [webcomponent myself](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/SieBrum/brum-global-variable).
usage:

```
// Login component
// Define global variable
<brum-global-var key="username" value="{{username}}"></global-variable>

// welcome-page 
// Use global variable
<brum-global-var key="username" value="{{username}}" readonly></global-variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a mixin class and extend it in whatever component you need it. Read more [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#mixins).

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`iron-meta`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-meta/elements/iron-meta) element that can be used to do exactly what you created.